VB.NET SQL Server For each statement not working as required
My Table in database

Now in this table I have departments like 1 & 2.
I want to print separate tokens for each department.
This is code for reading unique departments from table (if available)
Public Sub token_print_()
openconnection1()
Try

    Dim searchQuery As String = "select distinct department as 'department' from tb_transactions where invoice_id='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(searchQuery, MYSQLCon)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim table As New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(table)

    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
        For Each colu In table.Columns

            receipt_filldatagridview2(row(colu))

        Next

    Next

    command.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Receipt Fill Error 107")

 End Try 
End Sub

What I want is to read each unique department (like 1 & 2) and then fill the datagridview with this one by one and printing tokens. (by passing each department to receipt_filldatagridview2(row(colu)))
But the problem is For each statement is not working as it should. (datagridview only shows items with department 2 and skip the department 1 in each statement)
Here is code for datagridview
Public Sub receipt_filldatagridview2(ByVal dept As String)
openconnection1()
Try
    DataGridView_thermal.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    Dim searchQuery As String = "Select tb_transactions.product_name as 'product_name', cast(quantity as numeric(36,1)) as 'quantity', tb_transactions.rate as 'rate'  from tb_transactions  where tb_transactions.invoice_id = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND tb_transactions.department = '" & dept.ToString & "'"

    Dim command As New SqlCommand(searchQuery, MYSQLCon)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim table As New DataTable

    adapter.Fill(table)
    DataGridView_thermal.DataSource = table

    BTPRINT.PerformClick()


    table.Dispose()
    adapter.Dispose()
    command.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, "Receipt Fill Error 107")

    End Try
End Sub

Printing Invoice Steps
Private Sub BTPRINT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTPRINT.Click
        changelongpaper()
        PPD.Document = PD
        PD.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Black Copper BC-85AC"
        PD.Print()  'Direct Print
    End Sub

 Sub changelongpaper()
      Dim rowcount As Integer
      longpaper = 0
      rowcount = DataGridView_thermal.Rows.Count
      longpaper = rowcount * 15
      longpaper = longpaper + 240
  End Sub

  Private Sub PD_BeginPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PD.BeginPrint
      Dim pagesetup As New PageSettings
      pagesetup.PaperSize = New PaperSize("Custom", 285, 500) 'fixed size
      'pagesetup.PaperSize = New PaperSize("Custom", 250, longpaper)
      PD.DefaultPageSettings = pagesetup
  End Sub

Invoice Design
Private Sub PD_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PD.PrintPage
    Dim f8 As New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim f10 As New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim f10b As New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim f10c As New Font("Calibri", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim f14 As New Font("Calibri", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim f9 As New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold)

    Dim leftmargin As Integer = PD.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left
    Dim centermargin As Integer = PD.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width / 2
    Dim rightmargin As Integer = PD.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width

    'font alignment
    Dim right As New StringFormat
    Dim center As New StringFormat

    right.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
    center.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

    Dim line As String
    line = "****************************************************************"

    'range from top
    'logo
    Dim logoImage As Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("logo")
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(logoImage, CInt((e.PageBounds.Width - 150) / 2), 5, 150, 35)

    e.Graphics.DrawString("New York Street 15 Avenue", f10, Brushes.Black, centermargin, 40, center)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Tel +1763545473", f10, Brushes.Black, centermargin, 55, center)


    e.Graphics.DrawString("Item", f9, Brushes.Black, 0, 110)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Qty", f9, Brushes.Black, 150, 110)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Price", f9, Brushes.Black, 220, 110, right)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Total", f9, Brushes.Black, rightmargin, 110, right)
    '
    e.Graphics.DrawString(line, f8, Brushes.Black, 0, 123)

    Dim height As Integer 'DGV Position
    Dim i As Long
    DataGridView_thermal.AllowUserToAddRows = False

    For row As Integer = 0 To DataGridView_thermal.RowCount - 1
        height += 15

        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value.ToString, f8, Brushes.Black, 0, 117 + height)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(1).Value.ToString, f8, Brushes.Black, 152, 117 + height)
        i = DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value
        DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value = Format(i, "##,##0")
        e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value.ToString, f8, Brushes.Black, 220, 117 + height, right)

        Dim totalprice As Long
        totalprice = Val(DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(1).Value * DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(totalprice.ToString("##,##0"), f8, Brushes.Black, rightmargin, 117 + height, right)
        '
    Next

    e.Graphics.DrawString("~ Thanks for shopping ~", f10, Brushes.Black, centermargin, 80 + height, center)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("~ Nosware Store ~", f10, Brushes.Black, centermargin, 95 + height, center)

End Sub


WARNING: Your code is dangerous. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, always, always parametrise your code. Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?

@ThomA Thanks for telling, but it is just sample code and I am using it for testing VB.NET desktop application

That it's test/sample code is irrelevant.

Also use Using to dispose, and don't cache connection objects. Anyway, really unclear why you are using an N+1 style loop (executing a new command for every row) and not just aggregating all the data you can get in one swoop.

It also makes no sense to For Each over table.Columns if it is known that there is exactly one column (table.Columns(0))

Also: use OPTION STRICT always, then you avoid issues with type conversions and learn how to write safe and performant code. I know that you don't use it because you pass an System.Object to the method receipt_filldatagridview2 which just accepts System.String. That should give you a compiler error.

As others have noted you need to parameterise your SQL queries.
You problem is you are calling receipt_filldatagridview2 once for each branch. But receipt_filldatagridview2 replaces the content of the data grid.
If you want to populate your datagrid with a SqlDataAdapter that data adapter needs to return all the data for the grid. Otherwise you'll have to write the code to fill the datagrid's data table yourself (ie. iterating over the results of each query).
Clearly the former is easier, and there seems to be no reason for the second query to be done separately for each query: do you need to simply order by tb_transactions.department so the results are grouped by department in the result?
Update
[Based on comments and update to the Q.]
Use of UI controls to transfer data from one part of the application to another is always going to create challenges.

I would avoid DataTable, it offers no benefit over collections of your own types and leads to manipulating data in memory that would be better done by the DB. It also means you can be type safe with named properties.
You can use DataTable if you are comfortable with it, but you do not have to associate it with a data grid.

Assuming you want to stick with DataTable and SqlDataAdapter (as you are used to these types):

Load all the relevant data for all departments into a single DataTable.

Populate the GridView with the DataTable.

Extract the list of departments from this into a List<T> or array.

For each department:
a. Get a collection of the relevant rows by filtering the DataTable's Rows collection.
b. Pass this collection to the function that builds the invoice.
c. The invoice code touches no UI controls.


Eg. code like:
i = DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value
DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value = Format(i, "##,##0")
e.Graphics.DrawString(DataGridView_thermal.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value.ToString, f8, Brushes.Black, 220, 117 + height, right)


Is much better to do as, within a loop over the extracted rows for this department:
dim rate as long = row.Cells(2).Value;
e.Graphics.DrawString(x.ToString("##,##0"), f8, Brushes.Black, 220, 117 + height, right)

Don't use cells in the DataTable as working variables: that impacts the display in the GridView. Keep concerns serparate!
(All those Cell(n) references with data conversions all mixed in would be improved with custom data types using the correct types.)

I have a code to print the receipt from data written to datagridview, for each department I want to print separate receipt. ( & there may be many departments that's why I cannot specify which invoice uses how many departments items), For this reason I used for each statement to fill datagridview each time and print and then fill datagridview for next department and then print and so on.

@AliAhmad you need to clarify in your Q: from this comment I think you mean you need to fill DataGridView_thermal for a department, generate invoice information, move to next dept. and loop? In that case that invoice processing needs to be in the loop. If the invoice process is manual then: have control to select the department (eg. drop down) and when a dept. is selected populate the data grid. Currently the loop over department loads the data grid for a department and then immediate goes to the next dept. and replaces the datagrid's content. Hence it ends with the last dept. data (1/2).

@AliAhmad ... give the query to get the departments does not have an order by clause which dept. is last depends on how the database returns data. A simple change to indexing on the database will change the order; and thus what is the last dept.. (2/2)

Yes you understood my question, Invoice processing is auto and in loop (not manual), & Currently loop over department moves immediately to the next department,
What need to be done to print and then move to next department, (I used wait but it still doesn't work).

@AliAhmad In that case show the invoicing step in the code in your Q,

@AliAhmad I don't do chat (too much else to focus on). Added more.... I dislike DataTable for anything other that being a DataGrid's backing store because it leads to hard to maintain code like this.
